# fusion tables map isn't showing

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I saved this code as an html file, but I'm not being able to visualize the map. I took the code directly from FusionTablesLayer Wizard 2.0. Is it something wrong with the code? I thought that it would be 'ready to use'. I need some help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    #map-canvas { width:500px; height:400px; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var layerl0;
    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 1,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "'geometry'",
      from: 1x46BzbRzLVz2S4_ml5Nx4oto2930DFrH39TM3uc
    },
    map: map
  });
}
function changeMapl0() {
  var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string-l0').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
  layerl0.setOptions({
    query: {
      select: "'geometry'",
      from: 1x46BzbRzLVz2S4_ml5Nx4oto2930DFrH39TM3uc,
      where: "'NOME' = '" + searchString + "'"
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <label>Escolha a cidade</label>
      <select id="search-string-l0" onchange="changeMapl0(this.value);">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="ALVORADA">ALVORADA</option>
    <option value="ARARICA">ARARICA</option>
    <option value="ARROIO DOS RATOS">ARROIO DOS RATOS</option>
    <option value="CACHOEIRINHA">CACHOEIRINHA</option>
    <option value="CAMPO BOM">CAMPO BOM</option>
    <option value="CANOAS">CANOAS</option>
    <option value="CAPELA DE SANTANA">CAPELA DE SANTANA</option>
    <option value="CHARQUEADAS">CHARQUEADAS</option>
    <option value="DOIS IRMAOS">DOIS IRMAOS</option>
    <option value="ELDORADO DO SUL">ELDORADO DO SUL</option>
    <option value="ESTANCIA VELHA">ESTANCIA VELHA</option>
    <option value="ESTEIO">ESTEIO</option>
    <option value="GLORINHA">GLORINHA</option>
    <option value="GRAVATAI">GRAVATAI</option>
    <option value="GUAIBA">GUAIBA</option>
    <option value="IVOTI">IVOTI</option>
    <option value="MONTENEGRO">MONTENEGRO</option>
    <option value="NOVA HARTZ">NOVA HARTZ</option>
    <option value="NOVA SANTA RITA">NOVA SANTA RITA</option>
    <option value="NOVO HAMBURGO">NOVO HAMBURGO</option>
    <option value="PAROBE">PAROBE</option>
    <option value="PORTAO">PORTAO</option>
    <option value="PORTO ALEGRE">PORTO ALEGRE</option>
    <option value="ROLANTE">ROLANTE</option>
    <option value="SANTO ANTONIO DA PATRULHA">SANTO ANTONIO DA PATRULHA</option>
    <option value="SAO JERONIMO">SAO JERONIMO</option>
    <option value="SAO LEOPOLDO">SAO LEOPOLDO</option>
    <option value="SAPIRANGA">SAPIRANGA</option>
    <option value="SAPUCAIA DO SUL">SAPUCAIA DO SUL</option>
    <option value="TAQUARA">TAQUARA</option>
    <option value="TRIUNFO">TRIUNFO</option>
    <option value="VIAMAO">VIAMAO</option>
  </select>
</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only missing thing are the quotes around the encoded table ids :-)

```js
function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 1,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "'geometry'",
      from: "1x46BzbRzLVz2S4_ml5Nx4oto2930DFrH39TM3uc"
    },
    map: map
  });
}

function changeMapl0() {
  var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string-l0').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
  layerl0.setOptions({
    query: {
      select: "'geometry'",
      from: "1x46BzbRzLVz2S4_ml5Nx4oto2930DFrH39TM3uc",
      where: "'NOME' = '" + searchString + "'"
    }
  });
}
```

I put your code on [jsFiddle with my correction](http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/vDGNy/).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding was that the encrypted doc id's only apply to the Fusion Table API but not to the GMaps API for Fusion Table layers.  Visit your table via the FT UI and select File -> About which will display both the Encrypted Id and the Numeric ID.  Try using the Numeric ID instead of the encrypted id:

```
layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "'geometry'",
      from: 1x46BzbRzLVz2S4_ml5Nx4oto2930DFrH39TM3uc  // change this to numeric id
    },
```

Comment: This should work, but I think it makes sense to switch to the encid if you use it somewhere else (i.e. if you use Fusion Tables API _and_ GMaps API).

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't realized the encid's were supported in the Maps API